# Then executes before the query is done

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I had this issue yesterday, but instead to ask about this I asked for a solution so I didn't learn anything. I have code that looks like this:

```
User.findOne({'user.id': author.id}, 'id', function (err, userid) {

  console.log(userid); //(1) executes after (2)
  newCharacter.character.author = userid;

}).then(() => {

  console.log('does it work? '+newCharacter.character.author); //(2) executes before (1): undefined

  newCharacter.save(function(err, character) {
    console.log('Success! ' +character.id);
  });
});
```

When I log `userid` in `then` it is still undefined for some reason. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing callbacks and promises. I don't think there is any guarantee that the callback attached to `findOne` will finish before the `then` gets to start executing.

What you probably want to do is pass the userid to the `then` instead.

```
User.findOne({'user.id': author.id}, 'id'})
  .then(userid => {
    newCharacter.character.author = userid;
    console.log('does it work? '+newCharacter.character.author);
    newCharacter.save(function(err, character) {
      console.log('Success! ' +character.id);
    });
  });
```

I've found this resource to be extremely helpful for understanding promises: https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html